# Bash for loop showing unwanted files/directories

Tags: bash, git

I'm trying to run a simple loop over some local git branches, but whenever I run the loop and echo the lines, I'm seeing it echo all of the files/directories in my current working directory. I don't have much bash experience so I'm confused why the outputs would be different.

```
git branch --merged
```

shows me what I expect, only branches.

```
for l in $( git branch --merged ); do echo $l; done
```

This is first showing all of the files/directories and then the branches, which I do not want to iterate over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current branch is marked with a `*`, this is being interpreted as a pattern that matches all files (expect those starting with `.`). Two options I see right away are:

1. Change the [Internal Field Separator](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html#IFSREF) to newline only.

   ```
   IFS='
   '
   for l in $(git branch --merged); do echo $l; done
   ```
2. Remove the `*` from the result.

   ```
   for l in $(git branch --merged | tr -d '*'); do echo $l; done
   ```

Comment: This still has glob expansion problems with `$l` and `$(git...)` being unquoted.

Comment: True, it's certainly not perfect, I was only addressing the immediate issue of the `*` being expanded to all matching files.

Comment: It helps, but it's not robust. If `git branch --merged` prints out `* master` and there's a file named `foo master` in the current directory this'll print out `foo master`.

Comment: Very good point @JohnKugelman. Based on the question it's still possible that removing or otherwise preprocessing the branch names to sanitize them might be an option, as in my option #2. I was actually trying to keep my answer succinct and not provide a complete solution since I don't know all the requirements.

Answer (score 3):

`*` will get expanded as a glob. To avoid this you need to quote the expansion of `$l`.

```
# Partial fix
for l in $(git branch --merged); do echo "$l"; done
```

Wait, that doesn't work. You also need to avoid `$(...)` being subject to glob expansion, which is trickier. To do that you could (temporarily) disable globbing:

```
# Works, but clumsy
set -o noglob
for l in $(git branch --merged); do echo "$l"; done
```

Not ideal: it prints `*` and `master` on separate lines. It also changes a global option that affects other commands. Better to leave shell options alone and use a `while read` loop instead.

```
# Best
while IFS= read -r l; do
    echo "$l"
done < <(git branch --merged)
```

There are two tricky bits here. One is using `while read; do ...; done < file` to read lines from a file. The syntax is weird but it applies the `< file` redirection to the entire loop. The other bit is using `<(...)` process substitution to use the output of `git branch --merged` where a filename is normally expected.

Comment: Or, if you don't want to mess with `IFS`, `while read -r; do echo "$REPLY"; done`.

Comment: I am interested in this use of `read`, I've only used it for user input myself. Couldn't you use the `-d` option to split on newline instead of setting `IFS`?

Comment: See: [Understanding “IFS= read -r line”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209123/understanding-ifs-read-r-line)

Comment: Plain `read -r` / `$REPLY` won't strip spaces either: [Live demo](https://tio.run/##PU07CoQwEO1zikEWUnkC6@0slu0WsZg1gwkMiUwCNt49mhF81fvy/ph9rbT4BDbEQhKR4ULecKFsGmVCF@J6W6YIBn5ky7WErLPihdS0cMDuAxPINYdeBnBJm/rVranA9Pq@P@Nv7gbjUqRaTw)

Comment: Exactly. If you use any variable name at all, `read` performs word splitting, which you can work around by setting the list of word delimiters to the empty string, so it won't find any. But IMHO it's cleaner to not specify a variable at all, which bypasses word splitting and directly assigns the line to `REPLY`.